# LaTeX word wrapping poorly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, ragged2e

LaTeX is not word wrapping this anything close to sanely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3.2in}
  \rule{3in}{5in}
\end{wrapfigure}
\raggedright
\parindent=0.5in

\lipsum[1]

%     Q 1
One of the greatest strengths of the Chase ad is that the information is
presented in two main different styles of text. One style, which presents the
narrative of the character in the ad, is handwritten, which personalizes the
story and catches the audience's attention. Since the ad campaign is for the
business card ``Ink'', it is fitting for the text to look like it is written by
hand and with a pen.

\end{document}
```

Which renders as:
[image: fail]

Notice the first line of the second paragraph, and be horrified. Why is that rendering like that? (Even the first paragraph is dubious...)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `ragged2e` package, and its `\RaggedRight` command (note capitalization) instead of `\raggedright`.  LaTeX's standard `\raggedright` command is [known](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ragright) to produce bad results like this.

Answer (score 15):

Replace `\raggedright` with `\RaggedRight` from [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package.

And (always) use [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package if you use pdflatex. With `microtype`, even justified two-column text is acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

Some improvements you may additional obtain with these definitions:

```
%% From "Latex Companion": Spaces between words:
\tolerance=2000
\emergencystretch=20pt
```