# Hyphenation of quote environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, hyphenation, quotation

Beamer turns hyphenation off.  There are good reasons for that (e.g., "if you need automatic hyphenation, you have too much text on your slides").  But I still get hyphenation inside a quote environment.  I think the reasons apply to quotes too.  A search in the Beamer manual and on the web does not show anything relevant.  Is there an option to completely turn hyphenation off in Beamer?

Comment: is this helping you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44556/hyphenation-in-beamer-presentations?rq=1

Comment: No, because that is about how to turn hyphenation ON, rather than OFF...

Comment: Check the answer [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44669](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44669/110998). It explains that hyphenation is not switched off in beamer but that it uses `\raggedright` instead of justified text. So you can try to redefine quote to use also ragged right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt the `quote begin` template to include `\raggedright`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtobeamertemplate{quote begin}{}{\raggedright}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{quote}
  \lipsum[2]
  \end{quote}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]