# beamer: column + babel + manual hyphenation does not work as expected

Tags: beamer, babel, hyphenation

- I have a `beamer` slide with a `footnote`.
- I use the `columns` environment.
- German has long words, e.g. `Teilnahmeberechtigt` (= "eligible") as seen in the example. Therefore I provide manual hyphenation as in `Teil"-nah"-me"-be"-rech"-tigt`.
- **Problem:** Still, the word is not split between two lines, any ideas?
- *I hope it is ok that the MWE contains the actual German text. This makes it easier for me to reproduce the issue.*

**Bonus question:** Where can I find a canonical list of available `shorthands` (e.g. `"=`) in `babel`? So far, I always go back to [this nice overview](https://homepage.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/georg.verweyen/silbentrennung.html) (in German).

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\begin{columns}
\column[T]{0.45\textwidth}

Als schönen Abschluss, habe ich am Anfang Februar 2023 den \alert{ersten Preis} bei den Woven Planet 2022 Invention Awards gewonnen\footnote[]{Zusammen mit den \alert{zwei Mit"-er"-fin"-dern} Julia Pralle und Hi"-ro"-shi Yasuda (TRI). Teil"-nah"-me"-be"-rech"-tigt waren ca. 8.500 Mitarbeiter.}, siehe xxx.

\column[T]{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.85\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{columns}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Related

- [Hyphenation in Beamer Presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44556)
- [beamer: Allow hyphenation by default (paragraph, itemize, footnotes, description)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678385) (follow-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It is setting the footnote `\raggedright` so even the small hyphenpenalty is avoided compared to a penalty-free `fil` stretch.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\begin{columns}
\column[T]{0.45\textwidth}

Als schönen Abschluss, habe ich am Anfang Februar 2023 den \alert{ersten Preis} bei den Woven Planet 2022 Invention Awards gewonnen\footnote[]{%
\rightskip=0pt
Zusammen mit den \alert{zwei Mit"-er"-fin"-dern} Julia Pralle und Hi"-ro"-shi Yasuda (TRI). Teil"-nah"-me"-be"-rech"-tigt waren ca. 8.500 Mitarbeiter.}, siehe xxx.

\column[T]{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.85\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{columns}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can I change this setting document-wide or frame-wide in beamer? I can Google it later, traveling at the moment.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehneroh probably but I'd have to know something about beamer, footnotes are not ragged by default so the footnote layout will have  key somewhere for setting this.