# beamer: Allow hyphenation by default (paragraph, itemize, footnotes, description)

Tags: beamer, hyphenation

- I want that all text in `columns`, `footnote` (incl. `[frame]` option), and `itemize` (and `description`) are set in a way that word breaks are likely to happen.
- This is a follow-up to [beamer: column + babel + manual hyphenation does not work as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678286) which teaches us that `\rightskip=0pt` is the solution and a cross-post, see https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=3702.
- **Q:** How can I modify the **default behavior** `columns`, `footnote` (incl. `[frame]` option), and `itemize` (and `description`) to behave as shown in the manually modified code example?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\myPHText}{Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\begin{columns}
\column[T]{0.50\textwidth}
%\rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
\myPHText%
\footnote{%
%\rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
\myPHText}%
\footnote[frame]{%
%\rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
\myPHText \myPHText}

\column[T]{0.50\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    %\rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
    \item \myPHText
    \item \myPHText
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Manually (= Locally) Modified Code with Desired Output

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\myPHText}{Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\begin{columns}
\column[T]{0.50\textwidth}
\rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
\myPHText%
\footnote{%
\rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
\myPHText}%
\footnote[frame]{%
\rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
\myPHText \myPHText}

\column[T]{0.50\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \rightskip=0pt % <-- Modified
    \item \myPHText
    \item \myPHText
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Related

- [Hyphenation in Beamer Presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44556)

Comment: Did you already try `\AtBeginEnvironment` or `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` hooks by any chance? If that works it would be an easy solution.

Comment: @Marijn I did not try the hooks. That sounds like a elegant idea. Could you provide an answer accordingly?

Comment: I tried it just now and sadly it doesn't work... the patches are applied ok but Beamer seems to move around the commands and contents in such a way that the `\rightskip` doesn't end up in a position where it actually has any effect.

Comment: Thanks, @Marijn for trying.

Comment: Wouldn't the sequence 
`\usepackage{ragged2e}`
`\let\raggedright\justifying`
`\justifying`
in the preamble, work?